# Datatables the angular way with $http brought data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

so I am working on an AngularJS app where I need to get data from the server using the $http service, like so:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'getAllClientLocations/' + session,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (response) {
    if (response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null) {
        $scope.locations = Object.keys(response.Result).map(function (key) {
            return response.Result[key]
        });
    }
});
```

And I am trying to display that data using angular datatables. The data displays well, and I get the datatables controls (pagination, buttons, search box) but none of them works and I get the "No data available in table" legend.

This is my html setup:

```
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ 'BRANCH' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'NAME' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'STATUS' | translate }}</th>
                        <th>{{ 'ACTIONS' | translate }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="station in stations">
                        <td>{{ station.LocationName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ station.StationName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ station.StationStatus }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editStation(station.CliLocationSalesStationId)" ng-stow="action.edit">Update</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="!station.HardwareFingerprint" ng-click="authorizeStation(station.CliLocationSalesStationId)" ng-stow="action.edit">Authorize</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="station.HardwareFingerprint" ng-click="deauthorizeStation(station.CliLocationSalesStationId)" ng-stow="action.edit">Deauthorize</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And these are my dtOptions:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDOM('frtip')
    .withButtons([
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel'
    ]);
```

I know there are some kind of issues due to asynchronization, the DOM is built before I get the data from the server. Is there a way to tell datatables to render after I get successfully data from the server?

Comment: Where you fill stations with data which is comes from web service

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromFnPromise(promiseFn)` as follows:

```js
//reference $q in your controller as service
//e.x anuglar.module("app",[]).controller($q,$scope..)


function getPromiseData()
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'getAllClientLocations/' + session,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function (response)
    {
      if (response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null)
      {
        $scope.locations = Object.keys(response.Result).map(function (key)
        {
            deferred.resolve(response.Result[key]);
        });
      }
      else
      {
         deferred.resolve("");
      }
    });

  return deferred.promise;
}



$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function ()
     {
         return getPromiseData();
     })
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDOM('frtip')
    .withButtons([
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel'
    ]);
```